# Converting EST to UTC in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a tool where everything is being saved as UTC and the GUI side only reflects EST (specifically EST as in Eastern Time that's static to UTC - 5.hours and does not follow daylight savings time.

So, if a user 'picks' a time, they're picking a EST time and I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do the EST to UTC conversion.     It looks like "in_time_zone" onlly has 1 Eastern zone and I'd assume offhand "Easter Time (US & Canada)" is really EDT (not EST):

```
    ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:name) 
    => ["Hawaii", "Alaska", "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "Arizona", 
"Mountain Time (US & Canada)", "Central Time (US & Canada)",
 "Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "Indiana (East)"]
```

Would the best thing to do simply be to add 5 hours (+ 5.hours) to a user selected EST time to store as UTC?

Thanks!

Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 1):

In config/application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

While storing, Use this:

```
in_time = (params[:in] + ' Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
          ).to_datetime.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').to_s
if in_time.match('-0400')
  clock.in = (params[:in] + ' -4:00').to_datetime.in_time_zone('UTC') if params[:in] != ''
elsif in_time.match('-0500')
  clock.in = (params[:in] + ' -5:00').to_datetime.in_time_zone('UTC') if params[:in] != ''
else
  <HANDLE ERROR> "ERROR: CANNOT FIGURE OUT TIMEZONE IN #{params[:in]}."
end
```

Comment: Did it help? If you found a better solution, please share it here. Can you accept the answer?